# Transitive verbs

Tags: глаголы

I would like to ask about transitive verb in Russian "играть".

According to dictionary this verb is transitive but there are common sentences such as:

"Дети играют во дворе"

"Команда играла плохо"

and others...

In these examples the verb is used without complements. As I know "во дворе" and "плохо" are prepositional and adverbial phrases, respectively.

So, what is wrong?

Comment: >So, what is wrong?   Either the dictionary or you reading it incorrectly. Can you quote the full article of that dictionary on "играть"?

Answer (score 8):

Just like its direct English translation 'play', 'играть' can be used in both transitive

```
Актриса играет роль - An actress plays a role
Оркестр играет вальс - The orchestra is playing the waltz
```

and intransitive forms

```
Дети любят играть на улице - Children love to play outside
Мне нравится играть с мячом - I like to play with a ball
```

However, there is some difference in use cases. Thus, for example, you can't say

```
Я играю пианино - I play piano
Я играю теннис - I play tennis
```

The correct versions would be with the prepositions

```
Я играю на пианино
Я играю в теннис
```

Answer (score 3):

There are verbs which can be both transitive and intransitive. Играть is one of them. The transitivity depends on the meaning, so if there is a complement next to the verb, the verb is transitive, and vice versa.

Compare:

Я *играю вальс* на пианино. играть1 'to perform (a song, etc.)'

Я играю в песочнице. играть2 'to entertain oneself'

Similar verbs: петь (Он спел песню vs. Девочка пела в церковном хоре), плясать (Он плясал во дворе vs. Спляши-ка нам вальс!)...

Answer (score 1):

A verb can be transitive or intransitive. And this quality depends upon its meaning. Since the verb играть has got a lot of meanings,  it can be both transitive and intransitive. Read the article from the dictionary by Ефремова

> Значение слова Играть по Ефремовой:
>   Играть - 1. неперех. Резвясь, забавляться, развлекаться. // Проводить время в каком-л. занятии, доставляющем удовлетворение, служащем развлечением одним лишь участием в нем.
>
> 2. Исполнять музыкальное произведение на одном или нескольких инструментах. // разг. неперех. Звучать (о музыке, музыкальных инструментах и т.п.).
> 3. неперех. Уметь пользоваться каким-л. инструментом или уметь ориентироваться в какой-л. игре.
> 4. Активно выступать, действовать в какой-л. момент спортивной или карточной игры.
> 5. Пользоваться для игры. // Приводить что-л. в действие, делать ход в игре, ходить в игре чем-л.
> 6. неперех. Обращаться с каким-л. предметом как с игрушкой. // перен. Относиться к кому-л. несерьезно, как к забаве, распоряжаться кем-л., чем-л. по своему усмотрению, не считаясь с чьими-л. интересами, желаниями. // перен. Обращаться с чем-л. легкомысленно, поступать неосмотрительно, не предвидя последствий.
> 7. перен. неперех. Заниматься какой-л. деятельностью несерьезно.
> 8. перех. Представлять на сцене, в театре. // Изображать на сцене, исполнять какую-л. роль.
> 9. неперех. Проявлять какое-л. качество, чувство, не имея, не испытывая его в действительности, притворяться, изображая собою что-л. // Пользоваться в своих интересах чем-л., что дает возможность воздействовать на кого-л.
> 10. перен. неперех. Сверкать, сиять, переливаясь разными оттенками, отражаться (о лучах солнца, свете, заре и т.п.). // Искриться, пениться (о вине, шипучих напитках).
> 11. перен. неперех. С живостью обнаруживаться, меняя оттенки своего выражения (о воображении чувств). // Находить выражение, отражаться.

Answer (score -1):

Trnansition and intransition of verbs have a special meaning of subject-object or subject-subject relations. Consider this (rude) russian proveb :

> Кто девушку ужинает, тот её и танцует

Both verbs are in wrong intransition to specificly show, that the girl is treated as a thing, not a person.

As for verb "играть": the game as a phenomen (tennis, footbal) and means of play are subjects ("играть в лапту" , " играть на трубе"), but the result or process of this play is an object ("сыграть хорошую игру", "играть Гамлета")

Comment: The quoted proverb breaks the rule using two normally non-transitive verbs transitively.

Comment: But it is an actual and known proverb. It is a good way to show what nuance of sense non-transitivity have.